# How to stop checking in bin and obj folders in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: tfs

I have followed all of the guidance around using `tfignore` files and VS still insists on checking in contents from these folders.  Is there some other way to go about this?  I'm getting really tired of excluding these things before every checkin.

Comment: Did you delete the "bin" and "obj" folder and then get the latest version before add the tfignore file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still use `.tfignore` file.

> If the changes are "still" in pending changes, first create a backup
>   copy, then make an Undo on them. Close VS, restore the backup copies
>   and then it should work.

Or you can also use a temporary quick fix for this problem: Add an `$` char into the bower_components folder name in the .bowerrc. TFS does not allow the `$` character in the file name, so it can't be added to source control.

More details, please see my and *Hoppe*'s answer in [vs2015 keeps adding project.lock.json to tfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38855760/vs2015-keeps-adding-project-lock-json-to-tfs/38863803#38863803)

---

Another way through source control.

You could try to remove the directory from source control(***not delete***), check in; and then delete the files/dir from Source Control Explorer and check-in in Source Control Explorer. Now TFS doesn't know about the files and won't compare them because they are not source controlled . Or you can also give a try with *Nate Kerkhofs*'s answer in [How do I permanently exclude the bin and obj folders from TFS 2012 checkin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21260039/how-do-i-permanently-exclude-the-bin-and-obj-folders-from-tfs-2012-checkin)

Comment: The first way didn't work.  But the second way did.  Thank you.